# How to move to another view after clicking a button?

Tags: button, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a login screen and there is some registration button and login button. When i will press the login button, i should move to registration screen which is basically a panel. How to move that?? Using handler or controller how can i do that?

Here is my senchafiddle link:

[SenchaFiddle Link](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#vSs3z#UuC3F)

Please help..

Comment: I tried in different ways. Basically for me both this Login form and registration form is Form Panel. So is it creating any probelem???
My latest code is here::
http://www.senchafiddle.com/#vSs3z#UuC3F#3MWeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to do is to give an action to the button

```
          action:'submitLogin',
```

which is handled in the controller.

```
         refs{
            nav:'#navview',
            submitButton:'button[action=submitLogin]',
               }

          control:{
        submitButton:{
            tap:'submitIt'
        }}
```

You can take the main view as a navigation view as

```
      Ext.define('App.view.Main',{

    extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype:'mainvi',
    requires:['App.view.Login'],
    id:'navview',
    fullscreen:true,
    config:{
    items:[{
        xtype:'login',
    }]
}
});
```

In this code the login page is placed at navigation view .Now if u want to move to another view u can just switch by pushing another view in the navigation view as

```
      submitIt:function(){
    this.getNav().push({
        xtype:'registrationscreen'

     });
     }
```

the above code can be written in the controller by declaring in the refs

where navview is the id of navigation view.

There is another method u can try.
there should be one main panel,put all ur views as items in that panel.
the layout of the panel should be card so that only one view is shown i.e login view.
After clicking the submit button u can move to another view by using the method

```
         setActiveItem(param);
```

where param is the index of the view in the panel.

Comment: So this means i have to create another view which is called mainview??

Comment: yes there should be a view which will hold all the views but one at a time.

Comment: and remember to add this main view to the viewport in the app.js file.

Comment: Hey thanks..i changed my code. Now i am keeping my login form and reg form in a single panel as u told. But when i am trying to move another view it is not moving. Here is updated link:: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#vSs3z#UuC3F#3MWeg#QigB5#qmerN

Comment: You will have to give an id to your main view class which is the main panel,then in the controller declare that in the "refs",this will create a getter method for that panel.Now you can use "this.getMypanel().setActiveItem(1);.well try this.

Comment: i changed it..    http://www.senchafiddle.com/#vSs3z#UuC3F#3MWeg#QigB5#qmerN            But it is not working..please check please.....

Comment: hey i tried but it is not allowing me to change ur code .Well what i saw that u are not using "#" with that id in the refs i.e '#mainpanel'.

Comment: ok i change it. But no luck. Can you please tell me what will b the line here: this.getMainpanel.setActiveItem(0);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12558/discussion-between-ice-box-and-arindam-mukherjee)

Comment: Hey thats done..thanks.. i used the below code:                          var a = Ext.getCmp('mainpanel');
        a.setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('registrationpanel'));
    },